# Embed PCP thermometers

Tags: civicontribute, personal-campaign-pages, pcp

I was wondering if it is possible to embed the thermometer from an individual personal campaign page to another site. I am guessing it is, but don't know where the best place to look for the code is: anyone know?

Comment: Yes, this would be a great widget to embed in a facebook page.  I think you have to do some coding as noted below by @rayWright

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could start with the widget code from a contribution page as a base?(Widget>widget.php)

Make a new one that pulls info based on PCP id vs contribution page id...